# Why are the Sith Inquisitors allowed to be Sith lords?

Tags: star-wars, obi-wan-kenobi

I mean, maybe they're not called "Lords". But in the new Obi-Wan Kenobi TV series, they walk around doing Sith/Jedi tricks in the middle of cities in plain sight while serving as commanders to Stormtroopers. Does this not **completely** break the [Rule of Two](https://disney.fandom.com/wiki/Sith#Rule_of_Two) that was established as early as [the-phantom-menace](/questions/tagged/the-phantom-menace) and continued in the original trilogy that took place after this series?

I thought the same about the [Knights of Ren](https://disney.fandom.com/wiki/Knights_of_Ren), but they were just mentioned in the movies, not really seen or used Sith/Jedi tricks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a distinction to be made here between Dark Side users and Sith Lords. The Inquisitors are Dark Side users, and they serve the Empire (and by extension, the Sith), but they themselves are not actually members of the Sith Order, therefore their existence does not violate the Rule of Two.

In *The Clone Wars*, it's shown that Sith Lords are able to train Dark Side apprentices of their own, on the condition that said apprentices are not powerful enough to threaten the Rule of Two. Specifically, Count Dooku/Darth Tyranus has the apprentice Asajj Ventress; she is not considered a Sith, and soon as her power level approaches Tyranus', Sidious orders her to be killed to uphold the Rule.

Likewise, in *Rebels*, it's shown that while the Inquisitors are more than a match for the half-trained Padawans that make up most of the surviving Jedi Order, they are no match for a fully-trained (former) Sith Lord in the form of Maul.

It's also worth noting that neither Kylo Ren nor the Knights of Ren consider themselves to be Sith Lords either. Indeed, Kylo Ren's philosophy, as espoused in *The Last Jedi*, is that both the Jedi *and* the Sith need to be destroyed.

Comment: I guess I thought the Rule of Two means usage Sith/Jedi force period. Although I have to say in 2 minutes so far Reva looks she can pretty much face any Sith lord/Jedi master.